# Timed Method Calls - How do I move on when time expires without waiting for operation to finish?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have an interesting scenario that I ran into, and I am having trouble determining what the best solution is.

Say I have the following foreach-loop

```
Request[] requestArray = //Get Array of Request objects from somewhere

foreach(IRequest r in requestArray)
{
      var response = r.MakeRequest();
}

public class Request:IRequest
{
       public double IntervalInSeconds {get;set;} //Allowed Time To Complete Request

       public Response MakeRequest()
       {
             //Perform arbitrary operation, could be long or short running
       }
}

public interface IRequest
{
       Response MakeRequest();
}
```

**Question:** What I need to be able to do is give each of the Request a value for **IntervalInSeconds** that specified how long that request has to return from **MakeRequest()** before we move on. For example, if we set it to 10, and 10 seconds passes by, I want to move on, and completely forget about the existing MakeRequest() call.

I have researched a lot of different ways that may be used to accomplish this, but not sure how to really do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < requestArray.Length;i++)
{
    var request = requestArray[i];
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<Response>(makeRequest);

    Task.WaitAny(new Task[]{task},request.IntervalInSeconds * 1000);

    if(task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
         /*Done*/
         return task.Result;
    }      
    /*Keep Going*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously the work being done in MakeRequest could last longer than IntervalInSeconds seconds. If MakeRequest had to run synchronously, it would be very hard to leave the method within IntervalInSeconds unless you got a loop there which allows you to check the elapsed time very regurlarly. Not a good approach.

Here's a quick and simple approach for your foreach loop that doesn't involve changing the interface IRequest:

```
foreach(IRequest r in requestArray)
{
  var responseTask = Task.Run(r.MakeRequest);

  await Task.WhenAny(responseTask, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.IntervalInSeconds));
}
```

This of course required that the method this foreach loop is in may be given a Task (or void, but don't do that) return type.

I could imagine more complex solutions, where MakeRequest takes care of the timeout interval itself, if you need it.